# Listbox items System.Data.DataRowView when inner joining query

Tags: c#, winforms

[here is two of my 'Ders' items(bottom listbox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRGGu.png)
it gets items but i cant display them, two output should come from query so query is correct.Something must be wrong in DisplayMember but i couldn't figure it out for 2 hours.

[here is the data that i receive from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXTOz.png)

and here is my code

```
private void kryptonListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bolumsilbutton.Enabled = true;
            bolumuduzenlebutton.Enabled = true;
            bolumupbutton.Enabled = true;
            bolumdownbutton.Enabled = true;
            derseklebutton.Enabled = true;
            derslistbox.Enabled = true;

            if (Connection.DBPath == null)
            {
                //burada bölüm ismine göre veri çekilecek(veritabanı olmadan!)

            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
                    string query;
                    con = Connection.GetConnection();
                    con.Open();

                    query = "SELECT Ders.ders_id, Ders.ders_ismi FROM Ders INNER JOIN (Bölüm INNER JOIN Bölüm_ders ON Bölüm.bolum_id = Bölüm_ders.bolum_id.Value) ON Ders.ders_id = Bölüm_ders.ders_id WHERE (((Bölüm.bolum_id)=" + bolumlerlistbox.SelectedValue.ToString() + "))";
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "Ders");
                    Connection.bolumlerform.derslistbox.DisplayMember = "Ders.ders_ismi";
                    Connection.bolumlerform.derslistbox.ValueMember = "Ders.ders_id";
                    Connection.bolumlerform.derslistbox.DataSource = ds.Tables["Ders"];




                    con.Close();

                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Veritabanına bağlanırken hata oluştu !" + ex.Message);
                }
            }



        }
```

Comment: I think you should remove the "Ders." part from the DisplayMember and ValueMember. You only need to specify the field names.

Comment: but as i show in the second screenshot when i put that dataset on the datagridview.datasource the field name starts with 'Ders.'.I have tried without 'Ders.' but its not working either.

Comment: Please don't put the answer into the question, you are welcome to answer your own question

Comment: I am sorry i didn't know @Charlieface should i edit it again and post it as a answer?

Comment: Yes, take the answer out of the question and post it below as an answer. Quickest way is to click the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73738367/revisions) link (where it says "edited x ago") and click Rollback to revision 1

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution if someone is having trouble to find it. I have changed the query this

`SELECT Ders.ders_id, Ders.ders_ismi FROM...`  to this

`SELECT Ders.ders_id as ders_id, Ders.ders_ismi as ders_ismi FROM ...`

and of course changed the display member and value member to this

`Connection.bolumlerform.derslistbox.DisplayMember = "ders_ismi"; Connection.bolumlerform.derslistbox.ValueMember = "ders_id";`